# Tailing log files in two different hosts

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, logs, pipe

I'm trying to tail two log files in different hosts and use the merged output as a single one.

```
ssh HOST_1 "tail -f MY_LOG_FILE"
```

I'm also using mkfifo to create a named pipe.

```
mkfifo MY_PIPE
```

The problem is. Outputting a local command to MY_PIPE works fine,  but when I output my ssh command nothing can be read on the named pipe (tail -f MY_NAMED_PIPE in another terminal)

```
mkfifo MY_PIPE

ssh HOST_1 "tail -f MY_LOG_FILE" > MY_NAMED_PIPE
```

The commands above generate no output on the pipe.

Is there any parameter to ssh command to pipe it correctly?

Is there another way to pipe it?

Comment: You show `MY_PIPE` and `MY_NAMED_PIPE`.  Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use *tee* with the append option *(-a)* to merge contents.

In terminal #1

```
ssh HOST_1 "tail -f /path/to/file" | tee -a /path/to/merged/contents
```

In terminal #2

```
ssh HOST_2 "tail -f /path/to/file" | tee -a /path/to/merged/contents
```

In terminal #3

```
tail -f /path/to/merged/contents
```

Comment: The problem is when lines are truncated by multiple lines written at the same time. –  Rafael Borja just now   edit

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh HOST_1 "tail -f MY_LOG_FILE" > MY_NAMED_PIPE
```

The tail program is going to buffer its output in blocks of 8 KB or so, because it's not writing to a TTY. If MY_LOG_FILE isn't very active, this may be why you're not seeing any output. Even if it were working, tail isn't writing full lines at a time, so the output from multiple tail instances would be badly jumbled.

You can tell `ssh` to run the tail command using a TTY. This should cause `tail` to buffer its output by lines instead. This should produce better results.

```
ssh -tt HOST_1 "tail -f MY_LOG_FILE" > MY_NAMED_PIPE
```

You can refer to the ssh man page [here](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh.1).

Comment: The problem is when lines are truncated by multiple lines written at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the following:

```
mkfifo MY_PIPE
ssh HOST_1 "tail -f /var/log/messages" > MY_PIPE
```

On the local machine I ran:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages > MY_PIPE
```

In another terminal on the local machine:

```
cat < MY_PIPE
```

The output of both remote and local `tail -f /var/log/messages` commands is visible.

The tutorial I followed is from [Linux Journal.](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156)

Comment: The problem is when lines are truncated by multiple lines written at the same time. –  Rafael Borja just now   edit